# extract a pattern if a number is higher than a specific integer using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I want to extract the lines that contain numbers which exceed a specific Integer for example if I have the following code

```
INTEGER ( 16 )
INTEGER ( 16 )
INTEGER ( 6 )
INTEGER ( 18 )
```

I want to keep only the lines that contain INTEGER (n <= 16), so I want to have as an output

```
INTEGER ( 16 )
INTEGER ( 16 )
INTEGER ( 6 )
```

Comment: Read a few sentences of the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins or glance over ANY awk tutorial you find online or even just the awk man page and the way to do this will be glaringly obvious. A **little** effort please...

Comment: @Ed Morton thanks for the book, do you have a similar one I want to learn "sed" too

Comment: You do not need a book to learn how to use sed correctly. Sed has a million complicated language constructs to do all sorts of weird and wonderful things which sed had to be able to do when it was first invented in the early 1970s but **NONE** of them have been useful since the mid 1970s when awk was invented. sed is still an incredibly useful tool but only for simple substitutions on individual lines so the only language constructs you need to know are s, g, and p (with -n) - all the rest have been obsolete for 40 years and are just used today for the mental exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be sure that there are always spaces before and after the digits, then you could use this awk:

```
awk '$3 <= 16' file
```

This simply checks whether the third field is less than or equal to 16.

However, it might be safer to use something like this:

```
awk -F'[^0-9]+' '/INTEGER *\( *[0-9]+ *\)/ && $2 <= 16' file
```

This sets the field separator to any number of non-digit characters, so the first field is empty and the second field contains the digits you're interested in. If the line matches the pattern (which is flexible with respect to spacing) and the digits are less than or equal to 16, the line is printed.